# Proper way to export constants in an API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, api-design

Which of the two solutions shown in the example below is **the proper way to export constants** from my API (a windows DLL) and why is it the superior alternative?

**Header file**

```
namespace ExampleAPI
{
    // Solution one
    extern const DWORD __declspec(dllexport) AKTION_OK;
    extern const DWORD __declspec(dllexport) AKTION_FEHLER;

    // Solution two
    const DWORD AKTION_FEHLER_DATENBANK = 2;
    const DWORD AKTION_FEHLER_XXX = 3;
}
```

**Cpp file**

```
namespace ExampleAPI
{
    // Solution one
    const DWORD AKTION_OK = 0;
    const DWORD AKTION_FEHLER = 1;
}
```

---

I think solution one is the better alternativ, because the constants are defined only once in the cpp file and not in every link unit that is including the header file. Correct me if I'm wrong. Although it lacks readability...

Comment: I don't think one way is more "superior" than the other, but rather a personal preference. I would personally use your second solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: What advantages do you see with the second solution?

Comment: Could these values ever change in a future version of the API? The main difference (apart from the ugliness of the first) is that the second gives clients a compile-time constant.

Comment: Use `enum`? Both on `class` and `namespace` interface it could be a solution.

Comment: Well, most of all readability, and as a user of the API I would greatly appreciate the possibility to actually see what the actual values are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the second solution, the compiler will know the constants, when compiling the application USING the API. This could allow the compiler to perform more optimizations.

The first solution has the advantage that you can change the constants without recompiling the application using the API.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see these solutions as equivalent at all.

One defines a compile time constant and one a link to a constant value. From the compilers point of view these are different when it comes to optimization: for example `(10+AKTION_FEHLER_DATENBANK)` can be compile-time evaluated in the case of solution 1 but not in the case of solution 2.

But there more important cases where they cannot be used interchangeably for example:
`case AKTION_FEHLER_DATEBANK:` is legal in case 1 but not case 2.

Similarly for `char Array[AKTION_FEHLER_DATEBANK]`.